# How do I get Okta to return a sorted API response?

Tags: okta, okta-api

I need Okta to return the resultset of `/api/v1/apps/{{appId}}/users` ordered by the created field. I see that I can filter: https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/events/#filters. But how do I sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no sorting functionality available for Okta's Apps API according to Okta's forum and their online documentation.  The Apps API is only capable of filtering: https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/apps/#list-users-assigned-to-application. Sadly, this is the one I needed.

However, as @Progman mentioned, Okta does support sorting on their User API: https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/apps/#list-users-assigned-to-application

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sortBy` and `sortOrder` parameters to sort the user list you want. See  the documentation for listing the users on https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/users/#list-users:

> **sortBy** - Specifies field to sort by (for search queries only)
>
> **sortOrder** - Specifies sort order asc or desc (for search queries only)